# Linting with pep8 failed

Tags: python, visual-studio-code

Suddenly today, after having used VSCode + python for a long time, I start getting the error "Linting with pep8 failed" with no more information.
Has the extension made some kind of breaking update? If so, where can I find information about what I need to do to fix this?

Comment: pycharm is so much better if you like it bloated but good... Else stick to pyscripter (new 2018 release)

Comment: sorry but SO is not the bugtracker for VSCode nor for pep08 linters